# Create list of json strings from list of pydantic objects

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pydantic

I am trying to get a list of json strings from a list of Pydantic objects and have done it in the following way:

```
raw_books = [json.dumps(x.dict()) for x in batch.books]
```

Everything works fine, but it seems to take a lot of time when the list holds thousands of elements. What would be another way to do this transformation more efficiently?

For example: 2000 list elements in **batch.books** result in execution times of around 5 seconds.

The pydantic model(s):

```
class Book(BaseModel):
    title: constr(min_length=1, max_length=128)
    authors: List[constr(min_length=1, max_length=128)]
    price: float
    year_of_publishing: int
    publisher: constr(min_length=1, max_length=128)


class BulkBook(BaseModel):
    books: List[Book]
```

Answer (score 0):

> *`2000 list elements` in batch.books result in execution times of around `5 seconds`*

So we are talking of about `5000/2000`ms for each `list`, right?

`2.5`ms for the conversion of a `list` (on which elements you are calling `json.dumps(x.dict())`) it's not such a long time I guess.

Comment: Turns out it is actually a long time. Using rapidjson instead of json improved the processing speed by 5 times.

Comment: So you found your solution in rapidjson? Nice to know.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a clear solution as results are not consistent. Sometimes I get the same time with different libraries.

Comment: @Ionut-AlexandruBaltariu maybe it's because of some caching mechanism

Comment: Can you also show an example of the book `pydantic` model?

Comment: I have added the models.

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_books = [json.dumps(x.dict()) for x in batch.books]
```

You are calling `json.dumps` inside the `list` comprehension, that seems to be a problem. That would be expected do cause a huge dip in performance, because `dumps` is called for each iteration in the loop.

The simplest solution would be to move `json.dumps` out of the `list` comprehension entirely:

```
raw_books = json.dumps([x.dict() for x in batch.books])
```

Comment: That would result in a single string that represents the whole list of books. I need a list of json strings that represents each book individually.